# Merge Pandas Dataframe with non-unique index with 1D Numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas Dataframe with an index, that is not unique.

```
index   col1  col2 
  1      a     b
  1      r     t
  2      e     e
```

And a 1D Numpy array with the same lenght as the Dataframe

array =  [g, h, y]

I need to add the array to a new column such as this:

```
index   col1  col2  array
  1      a     b     g
  1      r     t     h
  2      e     e     y
```

I have tried to make the array into a Pandas series and a dataframe, but get into trouble as the array has a different index.

I need to keep the non-unique index in the first dataframe. How can I manage this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can just assign an array as a column:

```
a = ['g', 'h', 'y']
df['array']=a
print(df)

   index col1 col2 array
0      1    a    b     g
1      1    r    t     h
2      2    e    e     y
```